# How to enable jEditable to perform updates?

Tags: 7, views

I recently installed the [jEditable inline content editing](https://www.drupal.org/project/jeditable) module on my Drupal 7 site, as an adjunct to the [DataTables](https://www.drupal.org/project/datatables) module.

We need the ability to perform updates on data presented in a DataTable View. I get an error that it cannot connect to the DB.

Does anyone have experience and success in making this work?

Or is there another module/jquery method I can use that does this?

**Note**: I cannot perform CRUD from a views interface (hence the name views) this would be a cool option though.

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking at the [Editable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews) module for a possible alternative. Here is a quote about it from its project page:

> ... lets you create Views where the fields can be edited. Fields show both the current value and a form to edit it. A 'Save' button allows saving of all the entities shown in the View.
>
> Editable fields can be added on the base entity as well as on entities brought into the View by a relationship. Other, non-editable fields may be added to the View, in which case they function normally.
>
> Currently, the following Views fields can be edited:
>
> - all FieldAPI fields
> - node title